# How to read csv

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, anaconda

I have a data stored in the csv file like below format

```
892,3,"Kelly, Mr. James",male,34.5,0,0,330911,7.8292,,Q
893,3,"Wilkes, Mrs. James (Ellen Needs)",female,47,1,0,363272,7,,S
894,2,"Myles, Mr. Thomas Francis",male,62,0,0,240276,9.6875,,Q
895,3,"Wirz, Mr. Albert",male,27,0,0,315154,8.6625,,S
896,3,"Hirvonen, Mrs. Alexander (Helga E Lindqvist)",female,22,1,1,3101298,12.2875,,S
897,3,"Svensson, Mr. Johan Cervin",male,14,0,0,7538,9.225,,S
```

Data type for each **column**

```
1. int        6. int
2. int        7. int
3. String     8. float
4. String     9. float
5. float      10.String
              11.String
```

first column which starts with *892, 893, ... 897* should be stored in `int` format in `array`. Third column like *"Wilkes, Mrs. James (Ellen Needs)"* should be stored in `string` type. But, the third column is in `string` format but the length of character is **not** fixed, i.e. I don't know max length of character stored in this column

**I have done:**

```
 csv_file_object = csv.reader(open('trainData.csv', 'rb'))
 header = csv_file_object.next()

 data=[]
 for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)
    data = np.array(data)
```

but, above code reads **all the column** as `string` but many of them are **not in `string` format**, and stored the information in `string` format. On the other hand, if I did with `genfromtxt`, the third column is problem because it includes comma inside double-quota.

I hope to store each column with its own data type i.e. first column should be stored as `int` type.

**My expected array:**

```
892 3 "Kelly, Mr. James" male 34.5 0 0 330911 7.8292 NaN Q
893 3 "Wilkes, Mrs. James (Ellen Needs)" female 47 1 0 363272 7 NaN S
894 2 "Myles, Mr. Thomas Francis" male 62 0 0 240276 9.6875 NaN Q
895 3 "Wirz, Mr. Albert" male 27 0 0 315154 8.6625 NaN S
896 3 "Hirvonen, Mrs. Alexander (Helga E Lindqvist)" female 22 1 1 3101298 12.2875 NaN S
897 3 "Svensson, Mr. Johan Cervin" male 14 0 0 7538 9.225 S
```

As you see, if data is not available, `NaN` or its derivant should be put.

What should I read csv file?

Comment: What about `pandas.read_csv('data.csv', dtypes=[int, int, str])` ?

Comment: @mbatchkarov I don't know pandas, can I get the expected result in **array** or **matrix** with it? Can you write an answer with your way?

Comment: @mbatchkarov hey, how should I use it ? And first row is header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pandas library more ease, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("trainData.csv", dtype={'col1': int, 'col2': int, 'col3': str, 'col4': str, 'col5': float, 'col6':int,
                                  'col7': int, 'col8': float, 'col9':float, 'col10': str, 'col11': str})
df = map(list, df.values)
print df
```

**Output:**

```
[[892, 3, 'Kelly, Mr. James', 'male', 34.5, 0, 0, 330911.0, 7.8292, nan, 'Q'],
 [893, 3, 'Wilkes, Mrs. James (Ellen Needs)', 'female', 47.0, 1, 0, 363272.0, 7.0, nan, 'S'],
 [894, 2, 'Myles, Mr. Thomas Francis', 'male', 62.0, 0, 0, 240276.0, 9.6875, nan, 'Q'],
 [895, 3, 'Wirz, Mr. Albert', 'male', 27.0, 0, 0, 315154.0, 8.6625, nan, 'S'],
 [896, 3, 'Hirvonen, Mrs. Alexander (Helga E Lindqvist)', 'female', 22.0, 1, 1, 3101298.0, 12.2875, nan, 'S'],
 [897, 3, 'Svensson, Mr. Johan Cervin', 'male', 14.0, 0, 0, 7538.0, 9.225, nan, 'S']]
```

The csv file should look like this, as the first row will be the columns names

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11
892,3,"Kelly, Mr. James",male,34.5,0,0,330911,7.8292,,Q
893,3,"Wilkes, Mrs. James (Ellen Needs)",female,47,1,0,363272,7,,S
894,2,"Myles, Mr. Thomas Francis",male,62,0,0,240276,9.6875,,Q
895,3,"Wirz, Mr. Albert",male,27,0,0,315154,8.6625,,S
896,3,"Hirvonen, Mrs. Alexander (Helga E Lindqvist)",female,22,1,1,3101298,12.2875,,S
897,3,"Svensson, Mr. Johan Cervin",male,14,0,0,7538,9.225,,S
```

You can read more about pandas here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html

Comment: how can I reach first element namely 892 with panda dataframe? I did df[0:0] or df[0][0] but gives error.

Comment: `print df.ix[0, 'col1']` where 0 is the index and `col1` is the name of the column, 
or `print df['col1'].values[0]` @carenvanderlee

Comment: so many thanks. I'm a bit confused. If 0'th element is data namely 892, how can I get header from `df`

Comment: `print pd.DataFrame(df).columns`, will give you the columns @carenvanderlee

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood you quite well, but i think this will work for you.

I implemented another two functions that will decide whtether a string is float or integer.

If the string is an empty string i wrote None, although, you can change it to whatever you like.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

def isfloat(x):
    try:
        a = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def isint(x):
    try:
        a = float(x)
        b = int(a)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return a == b


csv_file_object = csv.reader(open('trainData.csv', 'rb'))
header = csv_file_object

data=[]
for row in csv_file_object:
    for index, cell in enumerate(row):
        if isint(cell):
            row[index] = int(cell)
        elif isfloat(cell):
            row[index] = float(cell)
        if not cell: # cell == ''
            row[index] = None  # you can change the value to whatever you like.
    data.append(row)

print data
```

**Output:**

```
[[892, 3, 'Kelly, Mr. James', 'male', 34.5, 0, 0, 330911, 7.8292, None, 'Q'],
 [893, 3, 'Wilkes, Mrs. James (Ellen Needs)', 'female', 47, 1, 0, 363272, 7, None, 'S'],
 [894, 2, 'Myles, Mr. Thomas Francis', 'male', 62, 0, 0, 240276, 9.6875, None, 'Q'],
 [895, 3, 'Wirz, Mr. Albert', 'male', 27, 0, 0, 315154, 8.6625, None, 'S'],
 [896, 3, 'Hirvonen, Mrs. Alexander (Helga E Lindqvist)', 'female', 22, 1, 1, 3101298, 12.2875, None, 'S'],
 [897, 3, 'Svensson, Mr. Johan Cervin', 'male', 14, 0, 0, 7538, 9.225, None, 'S']]
```

Comment: @carenvanderlee , My answer did not fulfill your question?

Comment: you said "I'm not sure i understood you quite well, but i think this will work for you."

Comment: it seems working but it's too much coding. I'm looking for light-weight solution. Besides, all column type is known at compiletime i.e. in your code, I mean too much if-else check.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using pandas, because the question is tagged pandas. Read the file like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', skiprows=0, index_col=0, 
            names='city_type name sex weight has_cat has_dog bank_balance body_fat_index car_mileage car_type'.split())
```

You will get a data frame like this:
[image]

I took the liberty of making up names for the columns.

Once you've read the data into a data frame, you can do all sorts of magic with it- have a look at the pandas tutorials (they are great). Here is one example

```
df.bank_balance.describe()

count          6.000000
mean      726408.166667
std      1170522.652019
min         7538.000000
25%       258995.500000
50%       323032.500000
75%       355181.750000
max      3101298.000000
Name: bank_balance, dtype: float64
```